# To prove an apparently obvious statement: if $A_1\subseteq A_2 \subseteq ... \subseteq A_n$, then $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i = A_n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

> To prove:$$\text{If } A_1\subseteq A_2 \subseteq ... \subseteq A_n\text{ ,then } \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i = A_n$$ using the axioms of ZFC Set Theory.

Honestly, this statement is **very obvious**, but I do not want to take that for granted. How can I prove this from the axioms, especially the axiom of unions?

I'm fairly new to ZFC Set Theory, so I don't know where to start. I do know that the Axiom of Unions (and Specification) gives rise to the definition of $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ for sets $A_1,...,A_n$ though. The uniqueness follows from the Axiom of Extensionality.

*My thoughts:*
We already know that the union exists, and it is defined such that for every element $x\in \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$, there exists at least one set $A_j$ such that $x\in A_j$. What's next?

Thank you!

**Edit:**
Induction works if the chain is finite or countably infinite. What if the chain length is **uncountable**? Does this result still hold, and if yes, how do we prove it?

**Edit 2:**
So now I wish to prove (or disprove) the following using the axioms of ZFC Set Theory:

> Consider an infinite set $A$, and an index set $I$ such that $$A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq ... \subseteq A_i \subseteq ... \subseteq A$$
> where $i\in I$. The index set $I$ is uncountable. We have $$\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i = A$$

Comment: Hint: Since $A_j$ is subset of $A_n$, $x\in A_n$

Comment: Yes, that shows $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \subseteq A_n$. What about the other way round?

Comment: Suppose $x \in A_n$ then for any set $A_i$ we have $x\in A_n \cup A_i$ and continue this argument from $i =1 $ to $n-1$

Comment: Can you please help me out with the edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is regarding your second edit. First of all denoting $A_1 \subseteq A_2 .... \subseteq A$ is not correct when the index set $I$ is uncountable and moreover you don't know the elements of $I$.

Take $A_i =(0,i)$ where $i\in (0,1)$ and $A = [0,1]$. These are nested in the sense that $i \leq j$ implies that $A_i \subseteq A_j$ and observe that for $i$ in index set $A_i \subset A$. Clearly union of all $A_i$ is the interval $(0,1)$ which is not $A$.

Comment: Or when $A=\Bbb R$ for an even more stark example.

Comment: I'm not able to follow, how does $i\leq j \implies A_i\subseteq A_j$? $A_i = (0,i)$ is an ordered pair, so do you really mean $A_i = \{ \{0\}, \{0,i\} \}$?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine: Here $(0,i)$ is clearly the interval $\{x\in\Bbb R\mid 0<x<i\}$.

Comment: Haha alright, sorry for the confusion! Sounds good, thanks a lot for this counterexample :)

Answer (score 3):

To be completely formal, you'd could first prove by induction that $A_i\subseteq A_n$ for every $i\leq n$. Then prove that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\subseteq A_n$ and that $A_n\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$. This last one should be trivial by definition of the union.

As for the first one, if $x\in \bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i$, then $x\in A_j$ for some $j$, and then we know (from the proof by induction) that $x\in A_n$.

Comment: What if the chain is (uncountably) infinite? Induction would not work then.

Comment: The chain cannot be uncountably infinite as its size is a positive integer.

Comment: @JoshuaWang I don't understand. Given an infinite set $A$, is it not possible to construct a chain of uncountably infinite length such that $A_1\subseteq A_2 \subseteq .... \subseteq A_i \subseteq ....  \subseteq A$ where $I$ is some index set, $i\in I$?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine: Not in ZF, but even in ZFC, where it is indeed possible, why are you assuming that an infinite chain (countable or otherwise) must have a largest element?

Comment: No clue, I thought it was obvious. Turns out it isn't. Could you add some more details? @AsafKaragila

Comment: If it's possible in ZFC (**and why**), how do we establish $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i = A$ then?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine: Yes, it's obvious. Every chain is indexed by a linear order. Think of all those linear orders without maximal elements. (Also in ZFC it's possible to construct and uncountable chain of subsets of any infinite set, not that every chain has a largest element somehow.)

Comment: I think it's not possible to have a linear order without a maximal element. Isn't this Zorn's Lemma?

(Yes, I agree. Could you help me complete the proof in that case, please?)

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine The natural numbers with their usual order doesn't have a maximal element. Zorn's lemma applies in cases where *every* chain (including infinite ones) is bounded, but this isn't generally true.

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine: It is a good idea to revise some of the basics, or take a step back from your work and have a night off. The facts that there is no largest natural number, no largest real number, no large rational number (despite all three being linearly ordered), should all scream at you. And if you don't see that immediately as obvious, I can only imagine that you're somehow sunk too deep into a corner that you convinced yourself is the truth, and a bit of distance would do you good. Since you mention ZF, might as well look at the "countable ordinals" as well.